# Scroll View is not working when keyboard is open

Tags: android, android-fragments, scrollview

I am using `ScrollView` for scrolling my layout.But not working in Fragment class when keyboard is open. I am novice with Fragments.

Here is my XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/settingLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_bg" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tree_iv_userSettings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/tree_transparent" />
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/sv_rl_user_settings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:isScrollContainer="true" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_rl_user_settings"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image1"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="110dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/frame_large" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/changepassword"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/image1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:hint="CHANGE PASSWORD"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textColorHint="@android:color/black" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editname"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/changepassword"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:hint="EDIT NAME"
                    android:maxLength="20"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColorHint="@android:color/black" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editphoneno"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/editname"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:hint="EDIT PHONE NUMBER"
                    android:maxLength="15"
                    android:numeric="integer"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColorHint="@android:color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/edittype"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/editphoneno"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="EDIT TYPE"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/notification"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/edittype"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="NOTIFICATION"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/togNot"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/save"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/on_button" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/save"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/notification"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:text="SAVE "
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="40dp" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image1"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="27dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomRelay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="7.5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Upload"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:background="#ededed"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Upload Photo"
                android:textColor="#8F8F8F"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/border1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/Upload"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:background="#939393" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/choose_existing"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/border1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:background="#ededed"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Library"
                android:textColor="#007AFF"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/border2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/choose_existing"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:background="#939393" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Camera"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/border2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:background="#ededed"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Camera"
                android:textColor="#007AFF"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/border3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/Camera"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:background="#939393" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cancel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/border3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="#ededed"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:textColor="#007AFF"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dropimg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/drop_down"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest code of that `Activity`:

```
android:name="com.treeapp.header.Header"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Comment: What error it shows?

Comment: @AownRaza It is not showing any errors.

Comment: show ur full xml code then

Comment: @MSGadag My Layout is not scrolling.

Comment: based on your current code,the layout with the id "changepassword" is not in the same parent layout.Clean your project and ideally you should get an xml error

Comment: and why is it `android:layout_below="@+id/changepassword"`?

Comment: ur layout is not scrolling cos it fits in the screen..

Comment: I have edited my XML code. Please have a look again.

Comment: is @MSGadag's comment true?

Comment: @Droidekas what u think buddy?

Comment: Please use wrap_content instead of match_parent in relative layout which is inside scrollView

Comment: Scroll view is not working when keyboard appears.

Comment: Remove android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden" anf try

Comment: Please do use LinearLayout with vertical orientation Instead of Relative Lay out

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya is it mandatory to use Linear Layout?

Comment: @ShoebAhmedSiddique I checked your xml . Use layout weight for better approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this in ur manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysVisible"
```

Comment: to implement scroll..wrap content will fit the screen.. so it will not scroll

Comment: I dont think harcoded height is the solution to this issue.

Comment: read my ans again i stated that it might be not expected result..and ans to my second cmt..

Comment: wrap_content will not fit the screen, match_parent will and thus wrap_content must be used

Comment: But I still dont think it is the right solution, the mistake is mathc_parent instead of wrap_content, if layout is fitting in screen why would he need a scroller

Comment: Because this is not the way to answer the question, this is the suggestion not an answer , sorry :)

Comment: @ShoebAhmedSiddique check my editted ans.. i have added code for manifest

Answer (score 2):

I am sugesting you to use LinearLayout instead of relative layout with vertical orientation layout in which you are using scroll
and to hide your keyboard you can use the below code when you scroll the view 
just use

```
ScrollView anyname;
anyname =(ScrollView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.sv_rl_user_settings);
anyname.setparentView.setOnTouchListener(this);



@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getactivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getactivity().getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            return false;

        }
in your fragment java file i hope it will work
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but still not working.

Comment: is the scroll view parental or child ??

Comment: Please have a look again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67967/discussion-between-shoeb-ahmed-siddique-and-hanish-sharma).

Comment: see my edited answer which will solve the keyboard related problem @ShoebAhmedSiddique

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67973/discussion-between-hanish-sharma-and-shoeb-ahmed-siddique).

Answer (score 1):

Remove Gravity from First child of ScrollView. And Add Following lines in your scrollView

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysVisible" use this to make scrollview to work even if keyboard popups

Answer (score 0):

Just **remove** below code from your **manifest** file in **activity** tag

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your manifest
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysVisible"`

Answer (score 0):

> change windowFullscreen true to false it will work!!!
>
> ***`<item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>`***
>
> Enjoy Coding!!!!

Answer (score -2):

ScrollView should contain LinearLayout as the inner childView, you could add a LinearLayout out of the RelativeLayout like this:

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv_rl_user_settings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:isScrollContainer="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_rl_user_settings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center" >
```

Comment: I dont think so... Only one child must be there this is the only rule.

Comment: I always use like that, just try <ScrollView  <LinearLayout><RelativeLayout /> </LinearLayout> </ScrollView>, ScrollView will work.

Comment: It will also work with <ScrollView> <RelativeLayout/> <ScrollView/>, you use it that way ,doesnt mean you must use it that way :)

Comment: you right :) , i was limmited with thoughts, maybe try this `descendantFocusability:blocksDescendants` in ScrollView

Comment: @ShoebAhmedSiddique and you are telling this now