# Android - CustomKeyboard hide some views in scroll bar

Tags: android, keyboard, hide, scrollview

My problem is that when my CustomKeyboard ( http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm ) open. it hide some views in my scrollview. this image summaries all the problem : [image]

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg22"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.averagercalculator.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#4D113e64"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="2dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_classeNom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_avg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="--,--"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout1" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout_mai"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@drawable/seph"
            android:showDividers="middle" >
        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>

        <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboardview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Rq : the items of scrollview are generated automatically by view inflate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>



<TableRow
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                android:gravity="right" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="--,--" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="TextView" />

            </TableRow>
```

Thanks,

Comment: check this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718355/scroll-view-is-not-working-when-keyboard-is-open/27718579#27718579

Comment: Thanks, I try this but my problem is that I don't use a normal keybard I'm using a Custom keyboard :(